# How to read a row one by one using for loop in python

Tags: python, csv, row

I want to use the For Loop and print a row one by one whatever i required.
here is my code:

```
import csv
with open("details.csv") as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:

        if['age'] == '21':
            print(row['Name'], row['age'], row['DOB'])
        else:
            continue
```

Here i want run the for loop until 6 times and also i want specific data of who ever age is '21', that person details only i want print, if it is other than '21' then skip the row. but my code is doesn't perform exactly like i want.
can anyone help me..?
Thank you :)

my csv is:

```
Name    age dob 
Arun    21  01/08/93    
Banni   20  05/11/94    
charan  23  23/03/92    
nani    21  04/05/93
```

Comment: So whats your output?

Comment: @kasra, it is not printing anything.. may be syntax error  i guess

Comment: is it ['age'] == '21' or row['age'] == '21'

Comment: @duck, i tried but both are not working

Comment: could you give us a sample csv content

Comment: @duck, please check it i've updated my question

Comment: working here just change DOB to dob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and your file and got an error.
Then I replaced tabs in your csv file with commas and capitalized "dob" to "DOB":

```
Name,age,DOB
Arun,21,01/08/93
Banni,20,05/11/94
charan,23,23/03/92
nani,21,04/05/93
```

Then the output was correct:

```
>>> 
Arun 21 01/08/93
nani 21 04/05/93   
>>>
```

Of course I changed Line 5 to `if row['age'] == '21':`

Answer (score 3):

Simple error: Try this

```
import csv
with open("details.csv") as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader: 
        if row['age'].strip() == '21': #error in this line
            print(row['Name'], row['age'], row['DOB'])
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: oh, post few top line(with header) in your `csv`

Answer (score 0):

Try This if you dont have specified the header in csv file

```
import csv
import sys

f = open("File_Name.csv", 'rt') #open the file reading 
print "Name\tAge\tDOB"
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == '21':     #Check the condition
            print "%s\t%s\t%s" %(row[0],row[1],row[2]) #print the columns
        else:
            continue
finally:
    f.close()                 #close the file at the end
```

and if the file has header as first line(Name,Age,DOB) then use following

```
    import csv #import csv package
    with open("details.csv") as csvFile: #open the file 
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        for row in reader: #iterate the file
            if row['age'].strip() == '21': #check the condition
                print(row['Name'], row['age'], row['DOB'])
            else: #skip if not satisfies the condition
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `DictReader` uses comma `,` as a seperator between two fields but your csv file uses tabs.

If you don't want to change your csv file the solution is to change the creation of your `DictReader` to

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
```

Next change the line `if['age'] == '21':` to `if row['age'] == '21':`.

Finally `row['DOB']` should be `row['dob']` as the field names are case sensitive.